# Can't set the state in hook

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I have a hook:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default (httpClient) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const reqInterceptor = httpClient.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
    setError(null);
    return req;
  });

  const resInterceptor = httpClient.interceptors.response.use(
    (res) => res,
    (err) => {
      setError(err);
      console.log(err);
    }
  );
  console.log(error);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      httpClient.interceptors.request.eject(reqInterceptor);
      httpClient.interceptors.response.eject(resInterceptor);
    };
  }, [
    httpClient.interceptors.request,
    httpClient.interceptors.response,
    reqInterceptor,
    resInterceptor,
  ]);

  const errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
    setError(null);
  };

  return [error, errorConfirmedHandler];
};
```

This hook handles errors ; when an error occurs I can get it with `console.log(err)` but the `serError()` doesn't set the state.
what is the problem?

I'm converting this class-based component to functional component using hooks:

```js
class extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        error: null,
      };
      this.err = () => {
        this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
          this.setState({ error: null });
          return req;
        });

        this.resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(
          (res) => res,
          (err) => {
            this.setState({ error: err });
          }
        );
      };
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      axios.interceptors.request.eject(this.reqInterceptor);
      axios.interceptors.response.eject(this.resInterceptor);
    }

    errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
      this.setState({ error: null });
    };


    render() {
      this.err();
      return (jsx)
  }
```

I have componentWillUnmount so I don't like leave it as class-based component but this make me made. the conversion is obvious and I'm logging the `err`  just beside the `setError()` and it's ok but the state is always `null`

Comment: You should move the interceptor setup inside the useEffect, otherwise, it gets added every render.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I did that. It doesn't work

Comment: Also, adjust the dependencies so that `useEffect` is called only when the `httpClient` changes.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I did that too but nothing change .

Comment: @EmileBergeron see the actual classe-based component that I'm converting from in edited question , please.